# Hibernate3 criteria query selecting too many fields

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I want to write a simple query to retrieve a list of USER with a simple restriction on CUSTOMER joined table.
I'm only interested by the USER entity.

If I write it using HPQL :

```
public List<Users> getAssociatedAdminObs(Integer pCustId) {
    Criteria crit = getCriteriaForObsAdmin("USER");
    crit.createCriteria("clients").add(Restrictions.eq("idCustomer", pCustId));
    return crit.list();
    StringBuilder hqlQuery = new StringBuilder().append("select u from Users as u join u.customers as c where c.idCustomer=:idCustomer");
    Query q = getSessionAndManageFilter().createQuery(hqlQuery.toString());
    q.setInteger("idCustomer", pCustId);
    return q.list();        
}
```

The SQL generated only Select all the fields from USER entity, as expected.

Now if I write it through Hibernate criteria API :

```
public List<Users> getAssociatedAdminObs(Integer pCustId) {
    Criteria crit = getSession().createCriteria(Users.class);
    crit.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
    crit.createCriteria("customers").add(Restrictions.eq("idCustomer", pCustId));
    return crit.list();
}
```

The SQL generated Select all the fields from USER entity but also from the CUSTOMER entity.

I'm using hibernate-core 3.3.1.GA.

I know I can use projection to work around the issue but my object will be transient, I also validated it works using a subquery to do my restrictions.

But I'm not happy with using workarounds and I do not understand why it would behave differently between the 2 code examples ?

It doesn't make sense to me to select fields outside of the asked entity.

Comment: Make user you have Lazy Fetch type between USER and CUSTOMER.

Comment: Yes, I've @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY). Either way I don't understand why these 2 ways would behave differently as they are both using the same entity ?